# context.Wait, messages are are still delivered to endpoint rather than the method to wait on

Tags: c#, botframework

Below is my Dialog.

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    async Task IDialog<object>.StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context?.Wait(RequestEmailAddress);
    }

    private async Task RequestEmailAddress(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        context.Wait(RequestEmailAddress);
        var thumbNailCard = new ThumbnailCard
        {
            Title = "BotFramework Thumbnail Card",
            Subtitle = "Your bots — wherever your users are talking",
            Text = "Build and connect intelligent bots to interact with your users naturally wherever they are, from text/sms to Skype, Slack, Office 365 mail and other popular services.",
            Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage("https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg") },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Get Started", value: "https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/") }
        };

        var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();
        resultMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
        resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment> { thumbNailCard.ToAttachment() };
        await context.PostAsync(resultMessage);
    }
}
```

After the card is sent, any user input is hitting the REST API endpoint and the method *RequestEmailAddress* is not called at all.

NOTE: Initially I forgot to add *context.Wait(RequestEmailAddress);* and did so only after a couple of run. Could it be the bot has already ran into infinite loop of not knowing the context?

I even tried clearing up the stack and clearing up the bot state. Nothing helped.

EDIT: Adding the message controller part

```
private async Task<Activity> OnHandleActivityType(Activity activity)
{
    switch (activity.Type)
    {
        case ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate:
            OnContactRelationUpdate(activity);
            break;
        case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
            OnConversationUpdate(activity);
            break;
        case ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData:
            break;
        case ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation:
            break;
        case ActivityTypes.Event:
            break;
        case ActivityTypes.Invoke:
            break;
        case ActivityTypes.Message:
            OnMessageReceived(activity);
            break;
        case ActivityTypes.Ping:
            break;
        case ActivityTypes.Typing:
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    return null;
}

private async void OnMessageReceived(Activity activity)
{
    var message = activity.Text;

    if (message == AppConstants.RegisterEmail))
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EmailDialog());
    }
}
```

Comment: Few more things i tried to reset things are

context.Done<object>(null)

context.FlushAsync()

Comment: So.. it's never reaching your method because of the If... remove the " if (message == AppConstants.RegisterEmail))" ... you always need to delivery a message activity to the dialog (then internally will be routed accordingly). I updated the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `context.Wait(RequestEmailAddress);` call should be at the end of the `RequestEmailAddress` method.

```
private async Task RequestEmailAddress(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    var thumbNailCard = new ThumbnailCard
    {
        Title = "BotFramework Thumbnail Card",
        Subtitle = "Your bots — wherever your users are talking",
        Text = "Build and connect intelligent bots to interact with your users naturally wherever they are, from text/sms to Skype, Slack, Office 365 mail and other popular services.",
        Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage("https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg") },
        Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Get Started", value: "https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/") }
    };

    var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();
    resultMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
    resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment> { thumbNailCard.ToAttachment() };
    await context.PostAsync(resultMessage);

    context.Wait(RequestEmailAddress);
}
```

Also, incoming messages will always hit your endpoint (because it's the entry point). Then they will be delivered to the dialog. That means that you need to update the `OnMessageReceived` method on your controller and remove the `if` check for the message text match otherwise the user message won't be delivered anywhere:

```
private async void OnMessageReceived(Activity activity)
{
    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EmailDialog());
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Still, any user input gets delivered to rest endpoint only.

Comment: Can you update the post with the code of the MessagesController?

Comment: Was this useful?

Comment: I moved all my handling to root dialog from where i call/forward. Seems to be working fine now.